# C#のメモリ使用量について

Tags: c#, .net

C#のWindowsフォームアプリケーションを作っています。
ビルド環境はVisual Studio 2010です。

数百件のバッチ処理を行っており、
LocalReportによる画像帳票の作成や、
WPFによる画像変換を行っています。

処理件数に応じて使用メモリ（プライベートワーキングセット）が増えていきます。
ハンドル数、ユーザーオブジェクト数、GDIオブジェクト数は増えません。

メモリリークの可能性もあるかと思い、
処理件数とメモリの利用状況をログに取りました。

すると、200件程度までは処理件数に応じてメモリを消費していきますが、
800MBぐらいで頭打ちになり、そこからは使用メモリ量が増えません。

このような場合、メモリリークを疑うべきでしょうか。
それともヒープ領域が空いている場合は、
なるべくメモリを使おうとしていると解釈すべきでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalReportのオブジェクトが削除されずにヒープに残っているのが問題でした。
以下の設定をapp.configに追加することによって、メモリの使用量は激減しました。

```
<runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

参考URL：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220915/very-high-memory-usage-in-net-4-0/34184809#34184809

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1以降であれば、[使用メモリを簡単にプロファイル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2017)できます。特に.NETの場合、具体的なクラス名も把握できます。800MBの内訳を確認したり、指定した２つの時刻におけるオブジェクトの増減などを調べることでリークかどうか判断できます。

第三者からは状況が分かりませんので、Visual Studioをバージョンアップし、ご自身で調査されることをお勧めします。